# Caching data when switching to full screen

Tags: android

I've got an activity which has a gallery that is backed by an Adapter with data that was slowly retrieved over the network. I want to be able to switch to full screen and use a gallery backed by the same adapter. I don't want to have to reload all the data over the network just because I switched to full screen mode. Do I need to cache the data (about 100 objects, each of which contains a string and a few images) temporarily and then reload it in the full screen activity or is there a better way? I tried getting a reference to the original gallery in the full screen activity, but findViewById() returned null.

Comment: Sounds like you should be caching regardless of switching activities or not. If the user leaves your app and comes back in.. should they have to download 100 things they just downloaded 2 minutes ago?

Comment: In most cases, yes. However, the app I'm developing retrieves content in a manner similar to StumbleUpon which is designed to be different every time you use the app.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. What happens when the user scrolls off of a view? Do you have to redownload the content for that view when it comes back on screen? If you do have to reload it then caching would be essential for sure. Plus then you can use that cached data in your full screen activity

Comment: Well it's not fully implemented yet, but for now the plan is to keep a "back stack" of about 40 objects in the adapter and basically just delete the oldest one as the user swipes to the right. The reason I don't want to store all the data that the user has already seen is because the data in the Adapter would become unbounded. As the user swipes to the right new data is retrieved from a background thread, so after 5 hours of using my app there would be an absurd amount of data in the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For images you could use LRU caching(both on disk and in memory). As for objects - use Serialization.

Comment: They are objects that will eventually have a bunch of things other than images, so I'll probably have to make them serializable. I'll mark this as the correct answer once I figure out that works. Is using a SQLite database the right next step?

Comment: You could use DB or implement Parcelable inteface for objects.

Comment: So if I make my objects Parcelable, store an ArrayList of them in a Bundle, pass the Bundle using putExtras() when I start the activity, and retreive the the ArrayList of objects in the subactivity, that should work?

Comment: Well, any more than one object and I immediately get out of memory errors with the serialization process. I'll have to try using a database then.

Comment: That means you're doing something funny.

Comment: I was serializing 20 bitmap images, not sure if that's considered too large to be serialized. Here's the error I got: W/dalvikvm( 6070): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40190560)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6070): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11
E/AndroidRuntime( 6070): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
...
D/dalvikvm( 6070): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 73K, 62% free 2939K/7687K, external 24993K/25734K, paused
 130ms
E/dalvikvm-heap( 6070): 200160-byte external allocation too large for this process.
E/GraphicsJNI( 6070): VM won't let us allocate 200160 bytes

Comment: Regardless, I just allowed the data associated with the ImageAdapter to be declared static. Unless there is a major reason I shouldn't be doing this, I'm satisfied.